# Multiple Username & Password Login

Tags: php, authentication

How do I edit login.php below to add some usernames and passwords? For example, username1 with password1, username2 with password2, etc. Please help me. thanks

```
<?php
    $error = "";
    if(isset($_POST['username'],$_POST['password'])){
        /*** You can change username & password ***/
        $user = array(
            "user" => "username1",
            "pass"=> "password1"
        );
        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $pass = $_POST['password'];
        if ($username == $user['user'] && $pass == $user['pass']) {
            session_start();
            $_SESSION['simple_login'] = $username;
            header("Location: index.php");
            exit();
        } else {
            $error = '<div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible fade in" role="alert">
                <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a>Invalid Username or Password !
            </div>';
        }
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

add more users to the array, and an easier structure would be

```
$user = array('bob'=>'bobspassword','kim'=>'kimspassword');
```

then check:

```
if(isset($user[$_POST['username']]) && $user[$_POST['username']]==$_POST['password']){
echo 'in';
}
```